# CSS selector: ID or class in parent but rule for child

Tags: html, css

I know how to set a CSS-rule für all elements of a type, all elements of a ID and all elements of a type and a ID. But I do not know how to do that if only the parent does have a class or ID.

I want to set the class in the table but I want to define the CSS-rule for the tables element.

E.g. Every TH inside a TABLE of class "ABC" should have red textcolor.

```
<table class="ABC">
<tr>
<th>should be red</th>
<td>should be black</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<th>should be black</th>
<td>should be black</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How do do this selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the descendant selector is simply a space.

`table th {}` select every `th` that is a child of `table`.

`table.ABC th` select every `th` that is a child of table with class `ABC`.

```css
table.ABC th {
  color: red;
}
```

if you want to select the immediate child of a selector you have to use `>`.

`table.ABC th {}` will select only if the `th` is an immediate child of `table.ABC`.

this `th` will match ( note this is not semantically correct h

```html
<table class="ABC">
 <th> ...</th>
</table>
```

while this `th` won't match

```html
<table class="ABC">
  <thead>
    <th> ...</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator

Comment: It's not only a child but a **Descendant** for direct child use [`>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

Comment: @Rounin you are correct the space is a `descendant` selector while the `>` is an immediate child selector. ( I will update my answer. ).